# My Friend System Changes the Session For Every User

Tags: php, html, mysql

I am creating a friend system but that has a page called profile.php.  This page is used for every member of the system. It looks like

```
            <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Profile</title>
<link rel='stylesheet' href='style.css' />
</head>
<body>
<?php include 'connect.php'; ?>

<?php include 'functions.php'; ?>

<?php include 'header.php';  ?>

<center><div class = 'user'>
<?php
if(isset($_GET['user']) && !empty($_GET['user'])) {
    $user = $_GET['user'];

} else {
    $user = $_SESSION['user_id'];
}

$my_id = $_SESSION['user_id'];
$username = getuser($user, 'username');

?>  

<h3><?php echo $username; ?></h3>

<?php
if($user != $my_id) {
    $check_frnd_query = mysql_query("SELECT id FROM frnds WHERE (user_one='$my_id' AND    user_two='$user') OR (user_one = '$user' AND user_two='$my_id')");
    if(mysql_num_rows($check_frnd_query) == 1) {
        echo "<a href = '#' class = 'box'>Already Friends</a>  |  <a href = 'actions.php?action=unfrnd&user=$user' class = 'box'>Unfriend $username</a>"; //This is where the profile page design will go.
    } else {
        $from_query = mysql_query("SELECT `id` FROM `frnd_req` WHERE `from`='$user' AND `to` = '$my_id'");
        $to_query = mysql_query("SELECT `id` FROM `frnd_req` WHERE `from`='$my_id' AND `to`='$user'");
        if(mysql_num_rows($from_query) == 1){
            echo "<a href = '#' class = 'box'>Ignore</a> | <a href = 'actions.php?action=accept&user=$user' class = 'box'>Accept</a>";
        } else if (mysql_num_rows($to_query) == 1) {
            echo "<a href = 'actions.php?action=cancel&user=$user' class = 'box'>Cancel Request</a>";
        } else {
            echo "<a href = 'actions.php?action=send&user=$user' class = 'box'>Send Friend Request</a>";
        }       
    }
    ?>
    </div></center>
    <div id = 'sidebar'>    
<ul>
    <?php  

        $my_id = $_SESSION['user_id'];
    $frnd_query = mysql_query("SELECT user_one, user_two FROM frnds WHERE user_one =     '$my_id' OR user_two = '$my_id'");
    while($run_frnd = mysql_fetch_array($frnd_query)) {
        $user_one = $run_frnd['user_one'];
        $user_two = $run_frnd['user_two'];
        if($user_one == $my_id) {
            $user = $user_two;
        } else {
            $user = $user_one;
        }
        $username = getuser($user, 'username');
        echo "<li><a href = 'my_ideas.php?user=$user' style=display:block;>Ideas</a>         </li>";

    ?>


    <li><a href = '#my_links'>Linked Ideas</a></li>
    <li><a href = 'settings.php'>Profile Settings</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
<?php
}   
} else  {

?>



<div id = 'sidebar'>
<ul>
    <li><a href = 'my_ideas.php'>My Ideas</a></li>
    <li><a href = '#my_links'>Linked Ideas</a></li>
    <li><a href = 'settings.php'>Profile Settings</a></li>
</ul>

</div>

<?php  } ?>     

<div id = 'user_content'>

<p>This is where the user_content should go.</p>

</div>  

</body>

</html>

// That is where it ends the site formatted it weird.  Also, the function get user is

function getuser($id, $field) {
    $query = mysql_query("SELECT $field FROM users WHERE id='$id'");
    $run = mysql_fetch_array($query);
    return $run[$field];
}
```

The problem with this is that every time I go to a users page that isn't the user I am logged in as the site logs me out and logs me back in as the other user.  Is there anything I can do to fix this?

Comment: username changes when you come back from another page?

Comment: you are just setting the session not starting.

Comment: basically yes.  For example if I'm logged in as a user 'test' and I visit another page for a user called 'example'.  On that page 'test' is signed out and 'example' is signed in.

Comment: Both your `else{...` `$user = $_SESSION['user_id'];` and `$my_id = $_SESSION['user_id'];` are fighting for control. The last one gets precedence, so check that.

Comment: Plus, your `function getuser($id, $field)` being below `</html>` how did that get there? That shouldn't be outside like that.

Comment: The reason I used the my_id and user is to compare the two.  For example I used the if/else statement to determine user.  Then I compared user to my_id to determine if the profile would be the current user of a different user.

Answer (score 1):

you need session_start();. to start the session.

Comment: In the included file connect.php, the session starts and the site connects to the database

Comment: Then edit your question and make a mention of it then. @user3167386

Comment: what do you mean.  The session just starts like you suggested.  So I know thats the problem.  The question didn't change

Comment: session_start() needs to be placed beofre any HTML has been sent. Move your includes to the very top. You also don't need to separate them out, put them all inside 1 php tag